# Responsive button creation

Tags: html, button, responsive

What command should be used to make any button responsive in HTML?

I want to make call us button responsive so that if anyone click call us on my website he/she can will be redirected to dialer and can call us using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand but I think its this.

```
<script>
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "dialer link";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("dialer link");
</script>
```